# Using _ in number presentation in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, delimiter

There became available from Java 1.7 ability to use `_` (underscore) character within numbers, to improve readability, like delimiting thousands in decimal: `123_456_789` 
or displaying conveniently credit card number: `1234_5678_9012_3456`.

I've just installed latest Java 8.0 (Eclipse IDE). And to support such a way - there is error advising me to redefine whole project as JRE1.7 (which is Java 7).

Was this feature removed from Java 8 or am I missing any point here ?

Comment: [No, it's still there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html). General advice: Don't user `int` or `long` to represent serial numbers/credit numbers etc.. Use `String` instead.

Comment: Check the version you have your project set-to.

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: Right Click Project-> Properties -> Java Build Path

Comment: File->New Java Project->...(Field)Use a project specific JRE: (the only option) "jre8".

Comment: Check what the value of "compiler compliance level" is.

Comment: How can I know my "compiler compliance level" ? What value should appear there ?

Comment: Right click on your project -> properties -> Java Compiler: tick "enable project specific settings" and set compiler compliance level to at least 1.7

Comment: Putting (Right click on your project -> properties -> Java Compiler: tick "enable project specific settings") JDK to 1.7 fixed it, thanks. I just want to understand: if I run Java 8, and for example I don't mind my project has no backward compatibility with 1.3/1.4/1.5/1.6/1.7. Why should I "downgrade" project to lower version ?

Comment: If you don't care about <=1.7 than there is no reason for "downgrading". Personally i would set this setting on 1.7 because this version is still active (Updates will be stopped around April '15)